# Using ML inequality

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I'm trying to work out the following integral:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1}{\cosh(x)} dx $$

by complex analysis methods and as a result of the contour I chose (a rectangle) one of the things I need to show is that the integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{idy}{\cosh(L+iy)} $$ goes to $0$ as L approaches $\infty$ using the ML inequality.

Could someone show me how to do this? :)

Comment: Note that this integral can be done with elementary methods since it equals $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{2e^x}{e^{2x} + 1} dx$. Now substitute $u = e^x$.

Comment: Oh that's cool!! Would you mind still showing me how to show that integral goes to 0? (This question is taken from my Complex Analysis textbook so I don't think I should be doing it the simpler way in this context)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\left\|2\cosh(L+iy)\right\|^2 = (e^{L+iy}+e^{-L-iy})\cdot(e^{L-iy}+e^{-L+iy})=e^{2L}+e^{-2L}+2\cos(y) $$
gives:
$$\left\|\cosh(L+iy)\right\| \geq \sinh(L) $$
hence the integral
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{i}{\cosh(L+iy)}\,dy $$
is bounded by
$$ \frac{\pi}{\sinh(L)} $$
in absolute value. That gives:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{dz}{\cosh z}+\int_{\pi i+\infty}^{\pi i-\infty}\frac{dz}{\cosh z} = 2\pi i\,\text{Res}\left(\frac{1}{\cosh z},z=\frac{\pi i}{2}\right) = 2\pi $$
but the LHS is just twice the original integral since $\cosh(z+\pi i)=-\cosh(z)$, so:

> $$ \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dx}{\cosh x}=\color{red}{\pi}.$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for posting a solution to my problem :) I just have one question which is why exactly did you square the absolute value of $2\cosh(L+iy)$ ?

Comment: @Faolan: because it is easier to compute $\|z\|^2$ by $\|z\|^2 = z\cdot\bar{z}$.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot @Jack D'Aurizio :) Really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Faolan: you're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \dfrac1{\cosh (x)} = \dfrac{2e^x}{e^{2x}+  1} $$

Use the substitution $ y = e^x$, we get $ \dfrac{dy}{dx} = e^x = y $.

$$ \int_{-\infty}^\infty \dfrac1{\cosh(x)} \, dx = \int_0^\infty \dfrac{2}{y^2 + 1} \, dy = 2 \arctan (y)\bigg ]_0^{\infty} =\boxed \pi .$$

Comment: Sorry this wasn't actually my question. I just wanted to know how to show the second integral goes to 0. Though I really appreciate this really quick method, this is for complex analysis so I can't use that :(